# Forms authentication timeout different for IE vs. Chrome/Firefox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox, forms-authentication

We have an Asp.net MVC 4 website that has been in production for several months with no problem. Until this morning, that is. All of a sudden people could only log in via IE. Chrome and Firefox both failed. After a bit of panicked debugging we found we could only log in if we set the forms timeout from

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="30" />
```

to

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="120" />
```

Can anyone tell me why this is? Nothing has changed in server configuration, and that field hasn't been changed in web.config from the initial deployment.

Comment: Timeout is determined by the server, not the browser, so something else is up.  Need more info.  Check the event log?

Comment: Timeout is determined by the server, but the mechanism is via browser cookie. And nope, there's nothing in the logs.

Comment: I guess the bigger question here is, WHY are they hitting the timeout at all?

Comment: Which authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: basic forms auth -- nothing special